# set CLASSPATH in Jruby 1.6.4

Tags: classpath, ruby-on-rails-3.1, jruby

How to set class path in JRuby 1.6.4 ?

I set my class path as

```
set CLASSPATH=
%<project_name>%\lib\java\ant-1.6.5.jar;
%<project_name>%\lib\java\ant-antlr-1.6.5.jar;
%<project_name>%\lib\java\ant-junit-1.6.5.jar;
%<project_name>%\lib\java\ant-launcher-1.6.5.jar;
%<project_name>%\lib\java\ant-swing-1.6.5.jar;
%<project_name>%\lib\java\antlr-2.7.6.jar;
%<project_name>%\lib\java\asm-attrs.jar;
%<project_name>%\lib\java\asm.jar;
%<project_name>%\lib\java\auriga-cryptolib.jar;
%<project_name>%\lib\java\bcprov-jdk12-137.jar;
%<project_name>%\lib\java\c3p0-0.9.1.jar;
%<project_name>%\lib\java\cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar;
%<project_name>%\lib\java\checkstyle-all.jar;
%<project_name>%\lib\java\cleanimports.jar;
%<project_name>%\lib\java\commons-collections-2.1.1.jar;
%<project_name>%\lib\java\commons-logging-1.0.4.jar;
%<project_name>%\lib\java\concurrent-1.3.2.jar;
%<project_name>%\lib\java\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;
%<project_name>%\lib\java\ehcache-1.2.3.jar;
%<project_name>%\lib\java\hibernate-tools.jar;
%<project_name>%\lib\java\hibernate3.jar;
%<project_name>%\lib\java\jaas.jar;
%<project_name>%\lib\java\jacc-1_0-fr.jar;
%<project_name>%\lib\java\javassist.jar;
%<project_name>%\lib\java\jaxen-1.1-beta-7.jar;
%<project_name>%\lib\java\jboss-cache.jar;
%<project_name>%\lib\java\jboss-common.jar;
%<project_name>%\lib\java\jboss-jmx.jar;
%<project_name>%\lib\java\jboss-system.jar;
%<project_name>%\lib\java\trg-dao-hibernate-0.5.0.jar;
%<project_name>%\lib\java\trg-search-0.5.0.jar;
%<project_name>%\lib\java\trg-search-hibernate-0.5.0.jar;
%<project_name>%\lib\java\trilead-ssh2-build213.jar;
%<project_name>%\lib\java\versioncheck.jar;
%<project_name>%\lib\java\xerces-2.6.2.jar;
%<project_name>%\lib\java\xml-apis.jar;
%<project_name>%\lib\java\jasperreports-3.7.6.jar;
%<project_name>%\lib\java\commons-digester-1.7.jar;
%<project_name>%\lib\java\iText-2.1.7.jar;
%<project_name>%\lib\java\jfreechart-1.0.12.jar;
%<project_name>%\lib\java\jcommon-1.0.15.jar;
%<project_name>%\classes\;
```

But Windows cannot load these classes. I even tried to set the class in Windows environment variables at that time its works. But I can't put these much classes there more over its bad practice.
Actually I'm migrating an app from 1.4 Jruby. In 1.4 the CLASSPATH works perfectly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I found the answer you need to load all the local classes in your project then load the other class.

In my case I load this class first

% project_name %\classes\;